# Printing with MS Office Word to specific printer (Multi threaded, no default printer usage)

Tags: multithreading, printing, ms-word, ole

What i want to achieve is to print to specific printer with word multithreaded.
The way it works using

```
Word.Application.ActivePrinter = "printer name";
```

it changes the default printer on windows, and use that when i print.
How ever in  a multithreaded environment, other threads can change on their word object the active printer, and it will change it on all word.ActivePrinter, since they are "binded" to the default printer.
For now i have just used lock() on the active priter and the printout() method. But the method is way too slow, the whole change active printer takes quite some time. and with locks on it makes the whole program slow.

So what i am asking, is there a way to print to specified printer without ever using/changing default printer, if so where should i look and where can i find it?

Kind regards

Edit:
Found this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216026

My solution:

```
 object wordBasic = word.WordBasic;
 wordBasic.GetType().InvokeMember("FilePrintSetup",
     System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
     null,
     wordBasic,
     new object[] {PrinterName,true },
     null,
     null,
     new string[] {"Printer", "DoNotSetAsSysDefault" });
```

with this i can print multiple documents at once.

Comment: I don't think it's supported to run multiple instances of Word or trying to multithread it.

Comment: I run every word in its own instance, and it work fine besides the activeprinter thing, found i could use wordbasic, i just cant seem to work on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
object wordBasic = word.WordBasic;
wordBasic.GetType().InvokeMember("FilePrintSetup",
   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
   null,
   wordBasic,
   new object[] {PrinterName,true },
   null,
   null,
   new string[] {"Printer", "DoNotSetAsSysDefault" });
```

found at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216026